# Sharepoint 2013 CustomAction CustomWebControl

Tags: custom-actions

I'm little confused with the creation of a custom WebControl for a CustomAction.

I was following this tutorial : https://weblogs.asp.net/jan/creating-hierarchical-menus-with-a-customaction-in-sharepoint, but in my case nothing happens.

I guess it is because I don't how to create the class which inherits from WebControl. How do I have to create this class? I have to click on "Add a item", then "User Control (Farm Solution only"? Or I have to click just on "Class" classic? But for the last solution, how can I add this class to my assembly?

Here the code :

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="Essai"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    ControlAssembly="XXX"
    ControlClass="XXX.Web.CustomisationSiteActions">
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

In CustomisationSiteActions.cs :

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XXX.Web
{
    public class CustomisationSiteActions : WebControl
    {

        // Add a the new "lol" menu item
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            MenuItemTemplate item = new MenuItemTemplate();
            item.Text = "lol";
            item.Description = "lol";
            item.Sequence = 2005;

            this.Controls.Add(item);
        }  
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add new item, select class give it a name inherit it from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl

Comment: Thanks, but I did it and nothing happens. I edited my post in ordre to show my very short code.

Comment: Just for your information, we don't enter in the method CreateChildControls.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the deployment target, add a safe control entry for your  namespace of the control rendering the menu item.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange! Please expand your answer if possible with perhaps an example of a safe control entry. Thanks [mod].

Answer (score 0):

I do not do back-end dev

From the client, run as a Snippet in ChromeDEV tools, it is:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var actions = web.get_userCustomActions();
ctx.load(actions);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var userCA = actions.add();
        userCA.set_location('Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu');
        userCA.set_group("SiteActions");
        userCA.set_sequence(922);
        userCA.set_description('MyDescription');
        userCA.set_title('MyTitle');
        userCA.set_url('MyUrl');
        userCA.update();
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            console.log("Site action link added");
        }, function (e) {
            console.error(e)
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but i'm always confused with my back-end dev.

Comment: Front-End rules, back-end is the Cobol/Fortran of 2017

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it didnt't find the assembly.
I had to change the value of "DeploymentTarget" to "WebApplication" in my Package.Template.xml.

Thanks for your help.